# How to post form to two different pages with a single button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form with a single button like below:

```
<form name="sampleForm" id="sampleForm" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="biosample" name="biosample" class="sample"/>
<input type="text" id="library" name="library" class="sample"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd" class="buttonsub" value="NEXT>>">
</form>
```

Ajax code is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var encoded_project_id = $('#encoded_project_id').val();
    $('#sampleForm').on('submit', function(){
    var target = 'windowFormTarget';
    window.open('', target, 'width=500,height=300');
    this.setAttribute('target', target);
    $.post('postdata.php', $(this).serialize(), function(){
      window.location.href = 'phases.php?edit='+encoded_project_id;
    }).fail(function(){
    window.location.href = 'sample.php?edit='+encoded_project_id;
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Now when button is clicked, I want to post the data from the above form in 2 pages - handler.php and postdata.php

Handler.php should open in a new javascript window and postdata.php should open in same tab and same window.

How it can be achieved?

Comment: make 2 ajax calls with same data to differnt pages and use $.when method to handle the both ajax calls callbacks

Comment: can you please explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: It would seem you are using jQuery, so change this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('sampleForm').onsubmit = function (e) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('POST', 'test.php', true);
        req.send();
    }
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sampleForm').on('submit', function(){
    $.post('postdata.php', $(this).serialize(), function(){
      console.log('success');
    }).fail(function(){
      console.log('error');
    });
  });
});
```

---

You should do two things. First add

```
<form target="_blank" action="handler.php"></form>
```

This will ensure when the submit button is clicked that the form will open a new window.

Then you need to intercept the submit like so:

```
document.getElementById('sampleForm').onsubmit = function(e){
  //xmlHTTPRequest function
  //This is where you send your form to postdata.php
}
```

The code above will be called first and you can send your form with the asynchronous [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object to `postdata.php` . After that function ends, the default behavior of the `form` will start and your `handler.php` will receive the form.

Comment: added in question. Please check.

Comment: @D.k add your ajax code to your question. You're using jQuery?

Comment: Thanku..this works :) One more thing what changes to do if i need to open that handler.php in new js window. Currently it opens it in a new tab as we have used _blank attribute

Comment: @D.k what do you mean by new js window?

Comment: I mean new browser window. We use javascript window.open method for that thing

Comment: @D.k yeah I noticed. However, it is not possible opening a browser window like that while using a form. window.open does not seem to be cross-browser friendly btw.

Comment: check my updated js code to open the window. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

you just to need two ajax call . Do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // if want to stop default submission
    $("#sampleForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on('click','#btnAdd',function(){
        send('page1.php',{'data1':'value'});
        send('page2.php',{'data1':'value'});
    });


});


function send(url,data)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            // success
        },

        error: function(data) {
            alert("There may an error on uploading. Try again later");
        },

    });


}
```