# after submitting form button redirect to 2 different page

Tags: php, ajax

i have html form and in that form when i click it redirect to paypal page but i want before redirect on paypal page it should go send.php and then paypal page

i have tried onclick function on submit button and inthat function use window location function for redirect to send.php page but it's not working page redirect only paypal page

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send" onclick="mymail()">

</form>
```

javascript code

```
<script>
function mymail() {
 window.location.assign("send.php")
}
</script>
```

it only redirect paypal page not redirecting on send.php

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using input type submit so when it will pressed it will take default form submit action which is on paypal.com

your on click is also working here (try to put alert in that it will execute) also work but the problem is when on click completes its execution it will continue execute the form's default action .

so if you want to redirect from your on click my mail() function then you need to add ajax to the javascript function

```
  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


function mymail()
    {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("frm").submit()
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "send.php", true);
  xhttp.send();

    return false;
   }
```

Comment: yes now page redirect to send.php but after send.php i want execute form action(paypal)

Comment: Ok in that case , you need to send ajax request to the server so it will first go to send.php and after completing send.php work it will go to the paypal website .Please check modified answer ,  I have changed it.

Comment: you can check answer given by @rch , he did the same.

Comment: here , onsubmit you have return false for form, how will be the form submitted at second time

Comment: @rch : yes, my mistake sir . I removed it now .Thanks for keep tracking sir.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add id for form and change onclick function as below

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frm">
    <input type="submit"  value="send" onclick="return mymail()">
</form>
```

and now use ajax call in mymail() to send.php and on success of ajax submit the form through javascript by form id as shown below

```
function mymail()
    {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("frm").submit()
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "send.php", true);
      xhttp.send();

        return false;
    }
```

now on click of submit, page goes to send.php through ajax and on success the form will be submiteed

Comment: great sir .. you give me exactly what i want. thank you so much sir, big heart from india

Comment: Thank you , and if this answer suits your requirement, feel free to upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

Submit button first event is to submit the form to your "action" location (paypal), the second event "onclick" is to redirect to send.php.

So if you want it to go to send.php first make the action send.php, do your thing there, than send your post data to paypal.
Take a look at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32197769/6340057

Answer (score 0):

First of all clear `action=""` and `method=""`, because even tho you change the button property, when the user clicks enter within that form, it will redirect to the given action no matter what your javascript does.

Secondly, change your `<input>` into a `<button type="button">` rather than `<input type="submit">` and call the `onclick="mymail()"` function there just like you did.

Here is how your form would look like:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="mymail()">Send</button>

</form>
```

Make sure you read all the form fields and put it into data.

Good luck.